# How to line up photos on front page with photos on back page - margins and spacing are reversed

Tags: microsoft-word

Found some cards to add to a game.  I have scanned (JPG) and added them to a WORD document and now trying to print them out.  There are 12 images on the front and 12 images on the back of a page.  I've used tons of paper and ink in trying to align them - there's got to be an easier way that I don't know about.  Help!!

---

It's for Talisman game adventure cards.  One side is the task, the other side says ADVENTURE.  I'm trying to figure out how to set margins and spacing for each side and then print two-sided.  The task image is a smaller dimension than the Adventure image so that it fits inside the lines.  Hoping there is a formula for margins, tabs, etc. that I just don't know about because most of my WORD experience is documents only.

Comment: What have you done, and why are they not aligned? In fact, how are they supposed to be aligned?

Comment: Why was my post deleted??  The cards were obtained legally and had been posted with permission.

Comment: Your *answer* was deleted by a moderator because it didn't answer your own question. The place to add information is inside your post by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1623425/edit) it.

Comment: Word might be the wrong tool for it. I would suggest using an image editing tool with layers, using the layers to line up the images appropriately (so have a front and back layer, and making one layer translucent while working to get the images lined up, then print them to identical sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to align an image might be to right-click on the images
and to choose *Wrap > Square*. Now the picture can be dragged to a known position,
for example against the right margin.

In more complex cases, where the simple way is not enough:

- Click *Layout > Margins > Custom Margins…*
- In this dialog, in *Pages > Multiple pages*, select "Mirror margins"
- Set the following margins:

  - Top : 2.5 cm
  - Bottom : 2.5 cm
  - Inside : 3.5 cm
  - Outside : 1.5 cm
- In the Paper tab, set "Paper size" to A4
- Click OK to exit the dialog
- Click the View pane, Zoom section, select "Multiple Pages"
- The margins should now be aligned.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to align 2-sided printing in Word is symmetrical](https://tipsmake.com/how-to-align-2sided-printing-in-word-is-symmetrical).